# rebuild html on jquery condition

Tags: php, jquery, html

**jQuery**

---

```
function(data) 
            {
                if(data === "importtrue")
                {
                    $('#rebuildme').//function like .html
                } else {
                    $('#rebuildme').//function like .html

                }
            });
```

with this, i'd like create html with PHP code.

**HTML/PHP**

---

```
     <div id='rebuildme'><?php print_r( $_SESSION['ERROR'] );?>
```

The function is a result of a $.post and $_SESSION['ERROR'] is created on the page the ajax requests too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery you need to capture the result of that service call and append it to the DOM for #rebuildme if it returns anything valid. I would suggest making it return 404 or something semantic so that $.get() fails silently until it has something valid to return.

```
if(data === "importtrue"){
  $.get('/myservice/import',function(data){
    $('#rebuildme').append(data);
  });
}
```